# Log4net External Configuration (C#)

Tags: c#, log4net

I don't know if it is possible to do the following using log4net.

I have a service which reads all its configuration at startup from a database. Within the configuration there is log configuration like "log level" and "logfile location".

The requirement is to write all the log, including the log from service startup to the log file location read from the database (this is of course if there was any problem connecting to the database).

A coworker wrote a very simple log class to fulfill this requirement, but I would really like to use log4net in order to use several features that log4net already provides.

Do you have any idea in how to make this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest hack is to read the existing configuration from database at startup, and then generate an external config file which matches log4net's format.

Then you can ask log4net to read this file directly, following "Reading Files Directly" section in this article,

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: That solve half of the problem, although the real "problem" is that the log from service startup will not be written to the logpath that is configured in the database. PS. I do not read configuration directly from database, the service is integrated to a framework that connects through an API that internally makes a TCP connection to a configuration server in order to get the service configuration. I'm interested in log this connection among other things to the configured logpath

Comment: Is it OK that you provide a set of default log4net settings at startup, so that before loading the new settings all log entries go to a default log file? That's a workaround which gives you enough information if you want to troubleshoot the connection. Alternatively, if you really want to write all log entries to "logpath", then you will have to cache log entries before loading new settings. I never did that, and I am not sure whether log4net already has some support for caching.

Comment: Exactly that support for caching is what I'm looking for. I don't know, maybe using a custom appender or modifying some property in log4net. I proposed the same workaround you suggested but apparently it is not acceptable, that's why we are using a very simple logger implementation a coworker did.